# Split string to only return the substring prior to the nth occurrence of a delimiter in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, parsing, split

Is there a way in Java script to return just the substring prior to the nth occurrence of a delimiter?

For example:

If I have a string `"test-123-example"` and want to only return the substring before the second instance of `"-"`, resulting in just `"test-123"`, is there a way to do that in one line?

I have tried using the `split()` function using (`"-"`) and using `indexOf()` to find the second `"-"`, but having no luck.

Answer (score 1):

From the above comment ...

> *"How about something as simple as e.g. ... `'test-123-example'.split('-').slice(0,2).join('-')` ... which [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)s, takes/[`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)s the first two items and (re)[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)s them again?"*

```js
console.log(
  'test-123-example'
    .split('-')
    .slice(0, 2)
    .join('-')
);
```

From the above example code the OP then could implement a generic approach in order to ... ***" return the substring prior to the nth occurrence of a delimiter"***.

```js
function getSubstringPriorToNthDelimiter(
  value, delimiter = '-', nthCount = 2
) {
  return String(value)
    .split(String(delimiter))
    .slice(0, Number(nthCount))
    .join(String(delimiter));
}

console.log(
  getSubstringPriorToNthDelimiter('test-123-example')
);
console.log(
  getSubstringPriorToNthDelimiter('test_123_456_text', '_')
);
console.log(
  getSubstringPriorToNthDelimiter('test_123_456_text', '_', 3)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of splitting, match with a regular expression to get non-dashes, followed by a dash, followed by more non-dashes.

```js
const input = "test-123-example";
const result = input.match(/[^-]+-[^-]+/)[0];
console.log(result);
```

- `[^-]` - Any character but a `-`
- `[^-]+` - One or more characters that aren't `-`
- `-` - A literal `-`
- `[^-]+` - One or more characters that aren't `-`